# Game Website Wrapper

Tags: software-engineering, web, webapp

I am looking to make a simple program (in any language) then when you run the .exe the only thing it does is display a website (the whole website is my game) without any navigation buttons as they are integrated into the pages.

Comment: From how you describe, your wanting to create a HTML reader, like firefox or IE. The fact that you want to limit your application to the single URL that hosts your game implies you dont need the the feature of user-input URL, and it likely doesnt need many other features, but its still a HTML reader.

Comment: Will it still run on the internet? So basically you want a "browser" that only displays a single page, without the normal browser buttons? Or must it all run on the user's machine?

Comment: Yes it will run on the internet erik and you got the jist of what i was tryong to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use WinForms and a WebBrowser-Form?
See [Browser class in WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) for reference.
WinForms is a Framework for creating Windows programs with C#. Basically you download and install Visual Studio, create a new WinForms project. There you've got a designer tool to drag and drop elements onto a basic window. In your case you would drag a browser element onto the form and with `browser.Navigate(URL)` you can show your website. Note, that you can also show a website/html document that is locally on your computer or included with your program. You can then compile and release your program as a .exe.

This is also very common on other systems than windows, maybe you want to read into the [Android WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) for example as well.

Comment: So i guess i should have explained better im looking to make somethig  without using an external program. Kind of like the downloadable launcher for minecraft i guess. But maybe i am missunderstanding what winforms is.

Comment: I've edited my answer to better show what I mean.. WinForms isn't an extra program, it's a programming Framework for GUIs. Using WinForms would still allow you to ship a simple .exe file (plus some DLLs probably from WinForms).